# SQL Select All Where the Concat is Distinct

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, concatenation

I am looking to create a select statement where I select all columns and rows when the concatenation of two of the rows is distinct. I have my SQL statement below. However, I am not sure how to properly create this statement, how would this statement be written?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM APPROVED 
  WHERE DISTINCT CONCAT(P_NUMBER,'-',A_NUMBER) AS CNUMBER 
  AND (STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED' OR STATUS = 'CLOSING' OR STATUS = 'PENDING')";
```

Comment: Are you sure this is targetting microsoft sql-server as tagged and titled? Syntax looks wrong. (`WHERE DISTINCT` and `TO_DATE` specifically)... or is that the question - how to convert that to SQLServer syntax?

Comment: Sorry this has been updated accordingly. I have an engine that renders mysql code for mssql.

Comment: It doesn't work then. mssql does not have a function `TO_DATE`

Comment: I removed the TO_DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISTINCT is used on the column selection. There are a couple ways to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(P_NUMBER,'-',A_NUMBER) AS CNUMBER FROM APPROVED WHERE 
AND (STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED' OR STATUS = 'CLOSING' OR STATUS =     'PENDING')
```

that should do almost the same thing as

```
SELECT * FROM APPROVED WHERE 
AND (STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED' OR STATUS = 'CLOSING' OR STATUS =     'PENDING')
GROUP BY CONCAT(P_NUMBER,'-',A_NUMBER)
```

the 2nd doesn't include the concatenation in the results, and the first one ONLY includes the concatenation. You'll need to specify all the columns to return.

Comment: So if I use the second query then I will only be pulling rows that are distinct because I would not want to pull rows that have duplicate entries for the CONCAT(P_NUMBER,'-',A_NUMBER)?

Comment: yes, but think about what happens if there are 2 rows with the same P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER. *which* values for the other columns do you want? You may need a grouping function like BIGGEST, SUM, AVERAGE, GROUP_CONCAT to make those columns meaningful

Comment: for example, you have two rows with the same P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER but one has STATUS='Closed' and the other is 'Active', you'll get one of those values, but you cannot predict which one.

Comment: So if the 2 rows have the same P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER then I just want the entire row of one of those results and then I want to ignore the rest of the results that have the duplicate P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER.

Comment: Vector, I do not understand. If you want only lines which have an unique couple, you can simply add `having count(*)<=1` to the second query. If you want only one line when you find copies, Garr Godfrey answered.

Comment: This may not make a ton of sense, but for my application I am just ensuring that the status is one of those values, it does not matter which one it is. I am just looking for a unique row and sometimes there may be duplicate row for the P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER but I do not care what the status is as long as the status is one of those 4 values.

Comment: if you want one row, you will get it. you just won't know *which* one. It isn't necessarily the first.

Comment: @ValBonn My query may retrieve many different rows that have unique P_Number and A_NUMBERS and I want to retrieve all of those rows. I just do not want rows with duplicate P_NUMBER and A_NUMBERS.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I just want unique rows, it does not matter which status I get. As I said above it is possible I may retrieve multiple unique rows and I would want to retrieve all unique rows that do not have duplicate P_NUMBER and A_NUMBER columns.

Comment: Then the group by should simply be `group by P_NUMBER, A_NUMBER` No need to concate

Comment: @ValBonn that sounds like a good idea. I will give it a try. Thanks.